# Namespaces in XML

Tags: xml, namespaces

I'm looking through previous exam-sets and one of the questions pertains to the usage of namespaces in an XML document. The question goes as follows:

---

What is the namespace of the element **foo** in the following XML document?

```
<xyz xmlns="http://baz.net" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org">
    <namespace xmlns:xyz="http://www.foo.org"/>
    <def xmlns:dwebtek="http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek">
        <foo foo:xmlns="http://www.bar.com"/>
    </def>
</xyz>
```

1. http://www.foo.org
2. http://www.bar.com
3. http://baz.net
4. The empty string
5. http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek

---

My initial thought was option 2. I noticed that they swapped foo and xmlns around in the foo element tag though. What impact does this have? Would this still be considered well-formed XML?

My second thought was then option 1, as in the xyz element tag they define the namespace for foo to "http://www.foo.org".

Checking the answer sheet however, it says the correct answer is option 3. Why is this? Could this be a mistake in the answer key? If not, why is option 2 incorrect?

EDIT: small correction

Comment: Technically, a namespace can't be the empty string, but it can be the "null namespace".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer is 3 indeed.

Let's review in detail what are the declared namespaces so that you can figure out why.

**First line:**

```
<xyz xmlns="http://baz.net" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org">
```

It declares two namespaces:

1. `http://baz.net` which is the default namespace URI for all unprefixed elements. This will apply to all elements in your document, unless another `xmlns` is encoutered.
2. `http://www.foo.org`, which is bound to the `foo` prefix. This namespace will apply only to elements (or attributes) starting with the `foo:` prefix, e.g. `<foo:bar>`

**Second line**

```
<namespace xmlns:xyz="http://www.foo.org"/>
```

It attaches the `http://www.foo.org` namespace URI to the `xyz` prefix. `<namespace>` tag is attached to `http://baz.net` namespace URI at this point, because it has no prefix.

**Third line**

```
<def xmlns:dwebtek="http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek">
```

It attaches the `http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek` namespace URI to the `dwebtek` prefix. `<def>` tag is attached to `http://baz.net` namespace URI at this point.

**Fourth line**

```
<foo foo:xmlns="http://www.bar.com"/>
```

There's a trick here, `foo:xmlns` is **not** a namespace declaration, because it doesn't start with `xmlns`. It is the attribute `xmlns`, with the `foo` prefix (and it's not advised to name an attribute *xmlns* even if here it is correct). Your element `<foo>` has no prefix, it is still attached to the default namespace URI thanks to the `xmlns` from the start, namely `http://baz.net` (and also because another `xmlns` has not been found anywhere else in the document).

**Note:**

With such a line in your document:

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.bar.com"/>
```

the right anwer would have been 2, this time.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the problem now. The naming of the prefix as foo and the element as foo tricked me there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So how can you tell that [potame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4214921/potame)'s explanation is actually correct?  It can be queried!

```
DECLARE @t XML = '
<xyz xmlns="http://baz.net" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org">
    <namespace xmlns:xyz="http://www.foo.org"/>
    <def xmlns:dwebtek="http://www.cs.au.dk/dWebTek">
        <foo foo:xmlns="http://www.bar.com"/>
    </def>
</xyz>';
```

```sql
-- To see the NS of the 1st foo element
select @t.value('namespace-uri((//*:foo)[1])','varchar(200)'); 
-- To see the NS of all foo elements  
select x.n.value('namespace-uri(.)','varchar(200)') from @t.nodes('//*:foo') x(n);
```

Thus proof that he is.

Comment: Good idea. With Java and DOM you could do something like (assuming that `doc` is the sample xml parsed in an `org.w3c.dom.Document` object) : `doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://baz.net", "foo")`  and check that the returned list contains your element/